# What's the different between Socket.BeginReceiveFrom and Socket.BeginReceiveMessageFrom?

Tags: c#

It looks like they have the same method signature. Is there any difference? When shall I use [BeginReceiveMessageFrom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.beginreceivemessagefrom?view=netcore-3.1)?

---

Why 2 people need more details, isn't the question clear? Please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

`BeginReceiveFrom()`  This begins to asynchronously receive data from a specified network device.

`BeginReceiveMessageFrom()` This begins to asynchronously receive the specified number of bytes of data into the specified location of the data buffer, using the specified `SocketFlags`, and stores the endpoint and packet information.

You can find more info the official documentation for the [Socket.BeginReceiveFrom()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.beginreceivefrom?view=netcore-3.1) and [Socket.BeginReceiveMessageFrom()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.beginreceivemessagefrom?view=netcore-3.1) methods.

Comment: Thanks, I've already read them, but I think the description for BeginReceiveMessageFrom  can also be applied to BeginReceiveFrom, isn't it?

Comment: I agree with you , both of them are an async operation and  have same parameters. 
returning result may have different values. maybe someone who knows better can write.